# How to convert bytes to an int using bit converter in c#

Tags: c#, bitconverter

I have a code that returns array of bytes which could be one byte or more or less. The problem relies in that when I convert the bytes some times I get an error because I can't determine when I need to use toInt32, toInt64, or toInt16. The other problem is that sometimes when I get one byte I am not able to convert this byte using these above methods because I keep getting errors. So how to determine based maybe on the length or size of bytes which method I should use.

```
//as in array of bytes byte[]
  var response = this.cc.Sendcc("SERIAL_NUMBER", 0x05, 0x80, 0x64, 0x04, 0x01, 0x21, (byte)1, (byte)1);

if (response .Length == 1)
{
     toInt32SerialNumber = BitConverter.ToInt16(response , 0);
}
else
{
     toInt32SerialNumber = BitConverter.ToInt32(response , 1);
}
```

Comment: Probably a moot question, but why not simply opt for the largest int possible then, i.e. int64 ?

Comment: _"I keep getting errors"_ - what errors?

Comment: Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check a

Comment: Why are you specifying the start index as `1` for `BitConverter.ToInt32(response , 1);`? Shouldn't that be `0`?

Comment: yes because the value at the zero index is always fixed and what I am checking against is the value at the second index

Comment: It would be helpful if you showed us the `response` contents for various lengths, and the result that you're expecting when converting those bytes.

Comment: If `toInt32SerialNumber` is an int32 then you can't assign an int64 to it (without data loss). Perhaps `toInt32SerialNumber` needs to be an int64.

Answer (score 0):

@moe1792

Please try this code,To convert bytes array to an int using bit converter in c#:

```
byte[] bytes = { 0, 0, 0, 25 };

if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian)
    Array.Reverse(bytes);

int i = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes, 0);
Console.WriteLine("int : {0}", i);
```

I hope above code will be useful for you.

Thank you.

Comment: There's no need to try to `@` notify the OP. 1) They get notified of answers automatically, and 2) `@` notifies don't work in answers anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try following, it will handle all possible values/bytes of "response":

```
if(response.Length<8)
{
    byte[] temp = new byte[8];
    response.CopyTo(temp, 0);
    response = temp;
}

UInt64 toInt32SerialNumber = BitConverter.ToUInt64(response, 0);
```

Further, StartIndex should be zero unless you need to skip some data intentionally!

Comment: It does not. If there are less than eight bytes in `response` it gives an error of "System.ArgumentException: 'Destination array is not long enough to copy all the items in the collection. Check array index and length.'"

Comment: Yes you are right. I think a little tweaking may solve it, i have modified my answer, please recheck.